# OS X only boots from redundant installer: how to instruct to use internal drive

Tags: macos, mac, boot, partitioning, efi

I installed OS X Mavericks on a external hard drive. This caused a problem I did not anticipate: I can no longer boot from the internal Yosemite installation.

How can I instruct OSX to boot from my Yosemite installation instead of the Install OS X Mavericks container? Am I screwed?

Details:

- If I remove the external hard drive and press the option key during startup there is only the "OS X Base System" visible.
- In single user mode I can see the system mounting an image from inside Install OS X Mavericks.app. [Full verbose startup output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXJOg.jpg)
- Everything from the internal hard drive is still accessible under "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" when running from external drive. However in Disk Utility there is no Partition Map Scheme for internal drive.
- The file /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot.plist on the internal drive has no instructions about mounting the installer DMG.
- bless --info command produces following results:

```
Blessed System Folder is /Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/Library/CoreServices

Blessed System File is /Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi

Open-folder linked list empty

No alternate OS blessed file/folder

Unused field unset

OS X blessed folder is /Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/Library/CoreServices
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be simple: the installer had converted my internal drive into a corestorage volume, and after reverting it back to HFS I could boot from my internal drive again.

```
diskutil corestorage revert /dev/disk1
```